# No Source Control On VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I feel like I have tried everything to have git show up on my vscode, and I need some help. I have the latest version of git installed 2.20.1.windows.1 on Windows 10. All I see is 'no source control providers registered' in vscode.

1. I have set git as an environmental variable. I've tried adding both "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" and "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd". Neither change anything in VS Code.
2. I have tried searching for anything related to git in settings. Nothing shows up.
3. I have tried git init into a directory and opening a file inside in VS Code. When this happens, it either opens or gives me '.git' file is not a directory.

Does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Git is incorporated into VS Code. Have you seen [Using Version Control in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)?

Comment: Same problem here. git is installed and I can clone using the command line. However it is not available within visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I spent so long on this. For me I had to go to the Extensions area > then click the ... at top right of menu > Show built-in Extensions

Git built-in extension was disabled!!

[image: screencapture]